# Need help about finding concave corner point of connected boundary of binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a problem that needs your help. I tried to do segmentation of rice grains following the method in "An Automatic Segmentation Algorithm for Touching Rice Grains Images" from Qing Yao. The first step of this method is to convert the image into binary and do contour extraction. After that they implement a method to detect concave corner points and search for corner point pairs, and this is my problem. Now I can construct the contours of the image but cannot detect the concave corner points. Here are my questions:

1. How can I detect connected regions and mark them for later calculation?
2. Is there any command that calculates the area inside the boundary in MATLAB?
3. In this paper they set the threshold for finding the concave corner by  `S=*R*R*A/360`. `R` is the radius of a circle and `A` is an acute angle,    but I didn't see any recommendations for setting `R` and `A`. How can I set these values or is there any command in MATLAB that I can use for this    purpose?

[image: This is the picture of contour of touching rice grains] 
[image: This is the picture of Detection of concave corner points]

Answer (score -1):

If the article doesn't well explain concave corner point extraction you may refer to other similar articles that explained the method. So I googled and found this paper:
TOUCHING GRAIN KERNELS SEPARATION BY GAP-FILLINGTOUCHING GRAIN KERNELS SEPARATION BY GAP-FILLING.
for connected regions and measure  their properties you may use these functions:

regionprops

bwconncomp

bwlabel